# TvInputService cannot be detected

Tags: android-tv

I conducted an experiment：If my app is signed with the system signature, the TvInputService cannot be detected. If the app is not signed with the system signature, the TvInputService can be detected. How can I resolve this issue?"

i hope to get your help，thanks